# How to check if Password reset link sent or not in flutter with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

**Here is my Code**

reset link is being sent to destination email without error.

**My Question is**

i just want to confirm that if the link is sent or not

```
await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email).then((val){

      }).whenComplete(() {
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
        if (isLoading) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("ERRORRRRRRRR=> $error");
      }); 


await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email).then((val){

      }).catchError((error) {
        print("ERRORRRRRRRR=> $error");
      });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this,

```
_auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email).then((onVal) {
  Navigator.pop(context, true);
  if (isLoading) {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}).catchError((onError) {
  if (onError.toString().contains("ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND")) {
    snackBarError(_scaffoldKey, "User Not Found", 1);
  } else if (onError
      .toString()
      .contains("An internal error has occurred")) {
    snackBarError(_scaffoldKey, Internet_Error_Msg, 1);
  }
  if (isLoading) {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
});
```